# Adding extra logic for authorization with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity

Is it possible to change the authentication logic in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that uses ASP.NET Identity/OAuth 2.0? I would like a user to be able to log on using his/her local account *or* using an external service (targeting the same user in the database).

The users are added to the database manually using a separate application (there is no "registration" for anonymous users available). This means that they have a local username/password and can sign on using these credentials.

As an alternative I would like to be able to allow these users to *also* sign on using their social accounts (Facebook, Twitter etc). This would need additional data in the database (something like "externalService" and "usernameWithExternalService"), data that will also have to be entered manually in advance.

Is it possible to accomplish this with ASP.NET Identity?

I have tried to find a way to hook into the framework and so far the best bet seems to be to implement a custom identity storage provider (implementing **IUserStore**, **IUserLoginStore** etc). Is this the right way to do it or is there a better "extension point" within the framework where this logic should go?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible. You can find sample code how to achieve that within ASP.NET Identity 2.0 sample project: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the pointer MarcinJuraszek.